# Returning value from data array based on several conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup, data-processing

I have a data table with 3 columns (the look is simplified for clarity, but arrangements and data formats are preserved, 1st column `A` is `Date` formatted with my regional settings, but it is NOT text):

```
Date        Module  Value
27.01.2013  xxxxx   90
27.01.2013  ttttt   100
29.01.2013  aaaaa   110
31.01.2013  aaaaa   50
31.01.2013  mmmmm   200
31.01.2013  ttttt   80
03.02.2013  ttttt   140
04.02.2013  aaaaa   120
07.02.2013  mmmmm   150
07.02.2013  ttttt   90
07.02.2013  aaaaa   190
08.02.2013  aaaaa   210
08.02.2013  aaaaa   90
08.02.2013  aaaaa   170
08.02.2013  ttttt   90
08.02.2013  ttttt   110
08.02.2013  mmmmm   130
09.02.2013  mmmmm   90
09.02.2013  aaaaa   200
```

The list may be quite long and updates regularly. What I need to achieve is this: on the same sheet I have the following calculated cells placed starting column E (i.e. there's a blank column D between data and calculated area):

```
MAX last week   Date        Value
aaaaa           09.02.2013  200
mmmmm           07.02.2013  150
ttttt           03.02.2013  140
xxxxx           <empty>     No change
```

Basically I need to find out from the data array in `A:C` the following:

1. For the list of values in `E` (which correspond to module name in `B`) Date and corresponding value which is **maximal among values for the same module**, but for the **last week starting today** should be returned.
2. If there are no records for this module during the last week - **Date should be empty**, and **"No change"** string should be for Value (as for `xxxxx` from the sample above, relating to the initial array and assuming today is Feb, 9).

As for the #2, I ended up with the following:

- For `Date`: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>TODAY()-7),--(A:A="xxxxx"))=0,"")`
- For `Value`: `=IF(F5="","No change")` (I check here corresponding Date on the left)

As for #1 - I'm stuck, and that's where I need guidance or advice. I tried different stuff with `MATCH`, `VLOOKUP` and similar, but not even close to success: I either have errors or not relevant results.

If that matters - dates are always sorted that more recent are in the end of the list, i.e. new records are added to the bottom. For the same Module may be several records during the same day. In case sample or explanation is not clear - please respond in comments and I'll add more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an array formula like this in G2 for value

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$100,">"&TODAY()-7,B$2:B$100,E2),MAX(IF(A$2:A$100>TODAY()-7,IF(B$2:B$100=E2,C$2:C$100))),"No change")`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copied down

and then for date in F2

`=IF(G2="No change","",MIN(IF(A$2:A$100>TODAY()-7,IF(B$2:B$100=E2,IF(C$2:C$100=G2,A$2:A$100)))))`

If there's more than one date in the last 7 days for that module where max value occurred that will give you the earliest (change MIN to MAX for the latest)

see [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i4ewwxzd9od2bq/max%20valuess.xlsx) for working sample

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with `=IF(F2="","No change",MAX(IF(A:A>TODAY()-7,IF(B:B=E2,C:C))))` for the Value. But what about Date? I can't figure out how to extend my solution to include dates from the past week...

Comment: Sorry, but the formula for the date returns circular reference if I use it together with my formula for value: I use Date field to check whether it is "" or not for "No change" case. Date and value are located in F and G respectively.

Comment: now both formulas return Values for me) sorry, perhaps for the Date one there should not be `C$2:C$100)))` in the end, but column B references instead?

Comment: shoot! - yes should be column A references (dates) at the end - I corrected and included an example....

Comment: I finished up with the following: `=IF(G2="No change","",MIN(IF(A:A>TODAY()-7,IF(B:B=E2,IF(C:C=G2,A:A)))))` - for Date, and `=IF(MAX(IF(A:A>TODAY()-7,IF(B:B=E2,C:C)))>0,MAX(IF(A:A>TODAY()-7,IF(B:B=E2,C:C))),"No change")` for value. Thanks for your help, and upvote for the efforts! Now itwould be nice to dynamically collect list of available modules - shall i submit a new question?